# How to change object in for loop each time loop is run

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, numerical-methods, runge-kutta

I'm trying to keep the detail to the minimum of what is relevant in this question, but I'll certainly expand on anything that makes my post clearer.

I'm pretty new to C++ so forgive me for what's perhaps an obvious question, I couldn't even articulate the problem well enough to find helpful search results.

I'm ultimately trying to code a leapfrog algorithm for planetary motion. I've defined a class called planet

```
Planet(double mass, double x0, double x1, double v0, double v1)
```

Then I have objects

```
Planet p0(2.0, -0.5, 0, -0.94, 0.65);
Planet p1(1.0, -0.6, -0.2, 1.86, 0.7);
Planet p2(1.0, 0.5, 1.0, -0.44, -1.40);
Planet p3(0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 1.15, -1.50);
```

I want to write a for loop which will run through each of these and take a particular component from each for a computation; computing Newton's gravitational force. I first wanted to test how I'd get a particular component from the objects.

I envisioned this being something like

```
for(int j=0; j<4; ++j){
cout << p[j].getvx() << "\n";
}
```

having already defined getvx(). It works fine when I try for example, p1.getvx().

So what my question is, how would I get p[j] for j starting at 0 up to 3 without having to type out p0, p1 etc? Can it be done in a for loop, is there some syntax I'm missing?

Comment: You're nearly there, look into http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily in a loop if you have a C++11 compiler:

```
for (auto& p : {p0, p1, p2, p3}}
{
    cout << p.getvx() << "\n";
}
```

Otherwise the easiest solution would be to make the planets an array rather than four individual objects.

Edit: To use an array, you could do something like this:

```
Planet planets[] = {
    Planet(2.0, -0.5, 0, -0.94, 0.65),
    Planet(1.0, -0.6, -0.2, 1.86, 0.7),
    Planet(1.0, 0.5, 1.0, -0.44, -1.40),
    Planet(0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 1.15, -1.50)
};

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(planets) / sizeof(planets[0]); ++i)
{
    cout << planets[i].getvx() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: When I try that, I get an error "error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'p' with no type [-fpermissive]|". 
I'm using the latest version of Code::Blocks so I assumed it'd use C++11. 

Perhaps it'd be easier for my purposes to put the planets in an array, but when they're objects of a class I don't really know how.

Comment: @user142340, turn on c++11.  I assume you're using g++?

Comment: Planet p[4] = {2.0, -0.5, 0, -0.94, 0.65, 1.0, -0.6, -0.2, 1.86, 0.7, 1.0, 0.5,     1.0, -0.44, -1.40, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 1.15, -1.50}

That seems pretty ugly, there's probably a nicer way to write it, but would this work?

Comment: @thang thanks, that got the original answer to work in my compiler. I'm still curious as to how I'd store the 4 objects in an array though.

Comment: @Jonathan In the parameters in your for loop, what's the 

    i < sizeof(planets) / sizeof(planets[0]);
doing? I get that is checks that i < 4 but what's the purpose of "/ sizeof(planets[0])" ?

Comment: @user142340 Total size of the array divided by size of one element = total number of elements

Comment: Ah, I see, that is a more general solution than what I would have coded based on my original attempt: i<4; 
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What if I want to run the for loop for all elements in the array except one predefined one, say p[2]. I thought of having 
for(int i=0; i<4 && i!=2; ++i) but that only gives p[0] and p[1] then stops, rather than giving p[3] as well and only excluding p[2]. Is there a way to exclude an element of choice from the conditions in the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Make an object array

```
    planet p[4];
```

Assign values to it

```
p[0](2.0, -0.5, 0, -0.94, 0.65);
p[1](1.0, -0.6, -0.2, 1.86, 0.7);
p[2](1.0, 0.5, 1.0, -0.44, -1.40);
p[3](0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 1.15, -1.50);
```

and then use it in loop
    
     `for(int j=0; j<4; ++j){
     cout << p[j].getvx() << "\n";
     }`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I store the information from p0, p1, p2, p3 in the array p[4]?

Comment: You can't do Planet p[4] without a default constructor, and you can't do p[0](2.0, -0.5, 0, -0.94, 0.65); without operator()